# Is installing unsigned UWP apps in Developer Mode in Windows 10 possible?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

According to [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/292914/what-is-developer-mode-in-windows-10/) and [this](https://pureinfotech.com/install-unsigned-windows-10-apps-powershell/), it should be possilbe, whereas according to Microsoft and the small description under the option Developer Mode ("Install any **signed** app and use advanced development features") and as I am personally experiencing, it is not possible.

So,

1. Is it possible or not?
2. If not, then what is the differenc to "Sideloaded apps" if the both do not allow installing unsigned apps and require the signing certificate to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not possible. The "Sideloaded apps" means can install and then run or test an app that has not been certified by the Microsoft Storeand. But the "Developer Mode" except sideloading, it enables debugging and additional deployment options. For more details about them, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development).